# Confirm input was found using a textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete a bunch of tags from a master list and I am having issues with the confirmation part. I managed to make the whole deleting process work, but I'm having trouble while trying to confirm that the tags have actually been deleted.

I have 2 textbox, one where the user enters his input, and another showing the results. I would like the second one to show either "Item Was Removed" or "Item could not be found".

I can't seem to figure out how to.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub BtnSubmit_Click()
    TxtResult.Value = ""
    Multi_FindReplace
End Sub

Public Sub Multi_FindReplace()
    Number() = Split(TxtNumbers.Text, vbNewLine)

    'Loops to find the asset tags through the list
    For x = LBound(Number()) To UBound(Number())
        'Confirms the Asset Tag is 7 characters
        If Len(Number(x)) = 7 Then
            For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                'Deletes the actual Asset Tag from the list
                sht.Cells.Replace What:=Number(x), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False
            Next
        Else
            TxtResult.Value = TxtResult.Value & vbNewLine & "Invalid C#"
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub Results()
    If TxtResult.Value = "" Then
        TxtResult.Value = Number(x) & " Was Removed!"
    Else
        TxtResult.Value = TxtResult.Value & vbNewLine & Number(x) & " Was Removed! "
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should publicly declare x as integer and your number() array at the top of your module. Then call the Results Sub after you successfully remove the asset tag from all sheets of the ActiveWorkbook.

I haven't tested the code, but it should look like this:

```
Public x as Integer
Public Number()
[...]

If Len(Number(x)) = 7 Then
        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            'Deletes the actual Asset Tag from the list
            sht.Cells.Replace What:=Number(x), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False            
        Next
        Results
    Else
```

See the Calling Sub and Function Procedures help file for details.